# Android QuickActions? PopupMenu? Popup Window?

Tags: android, popupwindow, popupmenu, android-popupwindow

I'm currently developing an Android app for a client. Problem is their mockup screens contained a UI view that I'm unfamiliar with. In short, I'm not sure what approach/implementation to use.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

The user taps on SALES TOOLS, and a popup of some sort appears with options leading to other features of the app.

Any suggestions on what implementation I can use?

Comment: There could be many ways.. one way you could be having a FrameLayout with background image as popup and hide/unhide on button click. FrameLayout will help display popup layout above any other layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **android.widget.PopupWindow** to create popwindow for a view.

using it various method you can put the window where ever you want.
Use this link will satisfy your needs .
**https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/how-to-create-popups-in-android/**

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of library Available in market

Please check this URL it may be help you links given below

1. [Chrome Style Help Popups](http://shardulprabhu.blogspot.ro/2012/08/blog-post_29.html)
2. [Quick-action-pattern-in-Android](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521455/Quick-action-pattern-in-Android-and-simple-impleme)

Another alternative would be "super-tooltips":

https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips